# dns cname redirect url

Tags: redirect, dns, cname

I have two domain names:

example1.com
example2.com

on example1.com i run an webserver in a shared environment on the internet. examle2.com is only a registered domain where i can only manage DNS. examaple1.com points to ip address: 123.123.123.123. the problem is, when i go to: http://123.123.123.123 i do not come on example1.com but to the website of my hosting provider. The problem is i need to redirect example2.com to example1.com, but i cant acomplish this with an A record because my hosting provider needs an domainname to redirect me to my site.

So how could i redirect example2.com to example1.com without changing the url?

Any ideas?

Sory for my bad english.

Comment: I have this exact same problem and ive been trying to get my head around A Records, CNAME's, DNS and .htaccess(mod_rewrite). I know its possible but i havent found a simple answer yet.. :S

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you go to example2.com? Same thing?

If so, you need to ask your hosting provider to add a virtual host entry for example2.com as well as example1.com

Answer (score 1):

you can't.
the only thing you can do by dns is to point a domain name to an ip adress.
what you need is a virtual host set up by your provider, that is configured to match the second domain.
if this isnt possible you need a webserver somewhere that serves a redirect of frame or something like that to your first domain